# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-install-plugin

I am trying to upload my artifacts to Nexus repository using Jenkins job. I have configured `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` for Maven. Below is the error I am getting after executing the job as per goal `deploy`, i.e. `mvn deploy`:

```
   Executing Maven:  -B -f
   /appl/tibco/cicd/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/pom.xml -s
   /appl/tibco/cicd/apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/settings.xml deploy -X
   Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1;
   2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00) Maven home:
   /appl/tibco/cicd/apache-maven-3.2.5 Java version: 1.7.0, vendor: IBM
   Corporation Java home: /appl/tibco/cicd/java/1.7.0 Default locale:
   en_US, platform encoding: ISO8859-1 OS name: "aix", version: "6.1",
   arch: "ppc64", family: "unix" [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
   [DEBUG] Reading global settings from
   /appl/tibco/cicd/apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading
   user settings from
   /appl/tibco/cicd/apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/settings.xml [INFO] Scanning
   for projects... [INFO]                                               
   [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Maven Default Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The POM for
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.2 is missing, no
   dependency information available [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.215 s [INFO] Finished at:
   2016-06-05T23:34:15+02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 39M/256M [INFO]
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data [ERROR] Plugin
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.2 or one of its
   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.2 in
   https://p-nexus.nl.eu.abnamro.com:8443/nexus/content/repositories/BPM-releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
   reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates
   are forced -> [Help 1]
   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.2 or one of its
   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.2 in
   https://p-nexus.nl.eu.abnamro.com:8443/nexus/content/repositories/BPM-releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
   reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates
   are forced   at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:133)
    at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:150)
    at
```

Comment: Is it possible that you add your output formatted nicely as it appears in Jenkins' Console Log? This will help readers of your question.

Comment: Above mentioned output is the complete output as per jenkins logs.

Comment: Regarding the content, probably yes. Regarding the format, most probably no. I don't know how others think about this but I personally refuse to deal with such badly formatted C&P. It may be my personal POV but I think instead of hiring a consultant and pay hundreds or thousands in the currency of your choice you're expecting an answer for free here. The least you can do in advance is presenting a question in a nice manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force clean your maven repo:
mvn clean install -U

Then retry the upload

Comment: `-U` is not to "_force clean_" it's to [`--update-snaphots`](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-deps-option).

Comment: I have already tried this. But it is resulting in error for maven-clean-plugin.